# How to calculate how many days to the person's birthdate from the beginning of their birthyear in C?

Tags: c

This us how much I've gotten

```
   int myd;
   int mym;
   int myy;
   printf("Enter your day of birth:");
   scanf("%d", &myd);
   printf("Enter your month of birth:");
   scanf("%d", &mym);
   printf("Enter your year of birth:");
   scanf("%d", &myy);

 int month;
   if (mym == 1 || mym == 3 || mym == 5 || mym == 7 || mym == 8 || mym == 10 || mym == 12)
{month = 31;}
   else if (mym == 4 || mym == 6 || mym == 9 || mym == 11)
{month = 30;}
   else if (mym == 2 && myy %4 !=0 && myy %100 ==0)
{month = 28;}
   else if (mym == 2 && myy %4 ==0 && myy %100 !=0)
{month = 29;}
```

I'm not sure how to increment the days of the months before the birth month.
If I knew that, maybe I can add that increment + birth date = no. of days until birthday from the beginning of their birth year

Comment: I think you want to add up (a) all the lengths of all the months before their birth month (you'll need a loop for this), and (b) the days before their birthday in their birth month.  So if their birthday is April 10, you'd have 31 + 28 + 31 + 10.

Comment: Eaza Kae, Can you use `mktime()`?

Comment: `int days_of_month = { 31,28,31 ...}; if( is_leap_year ){ days_of_month[1] = 29; }` ... Indexing into the array is a lot cleaner than a string of if/else statements.

Comment: Calculate the [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) for 1st of January and date of birth, then subtract.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array, which contains a number of days in each month. Each element beside the 2nd one will have a literal value, either `30` or `31`:

```c
int days_in_month[] = { 31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
```

For the 2nd element, representing February, you need to calculate the number of days based on the year. You already have that, but it is not correct. For example this condition:

```c
... && myy % 4 != 0 && myy % 100 == 0)
```

will never be true. Even after after changing the operator:

```c
... && (myy % 4 != 0 || myy % 100 == 0))
```

it is still not correct because it will match years divisible by 400, which are leap years. The correct condition is:

```c
(myy % 4 != 0 || myy % 100 == 0) && myy % 400 != 0
```

or for leap years (basically a negation of the above):

```c
(myy % 4 == 0 && myy % 100 != 0) || myy % 400 == 0
```

With that, the rest is just a loop through `days_in_month`, summing the values of days in months previous to the birthday, and at the end adding the day of month of the birthday. You can see the code in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x38TKjq5r). The output of some examples:

```
]$ echo -en "1\n3\n1900\n" | ./a.out
Enter your day of birth:Enter your month of birth:Enter your year of birth:
01-03-1900: 60

]$ echo -en "1\n3\n1996\n" | ./a.out
Enter your day of birth:Enter your month of birth:Enter your year of birth:
01-03-1996: 61

]$ echo -en "1\n3\n1997\n" | ./a.out
Enter your day of birth:Enter your month of birth:Enter your year of birth:
01-03-1997: 60

]$ echo -en "1\n3\n2000\n" | ./a.out
Enter your day of birth:Enter your month of birth:Enter your year of birth:
01-03-2000: 61
```

As a last point, one could argue that a year starts with Jan 1st, so there is 0 days from the beginning of the year to Jan 1st :-) If that's the case, just subtract `1` from the final result.

EDIT
One more thing, before doing any calculations, validate user inputs first. In particular that the month is between 1 and 12 (inclusive), or otherwise you will start reading garbage past the `days_of_month` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codes like this:

```
int mym;
int answer[] = {31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
printf("Enter your month of birth:");
scanf("%d", &mym);
if(mym==2){
    if(myy %4 != 0 && myy %100 ==0){
        answer[mym] = 28;
    }
    if(myy %4 ==0 && myy %100 !=0){
        answer[mym]= 29;
    }
}
else{
    printf("%d",answer[mym]);
}
```

I think you should use array ( like answer[] ) for convenience.